# loading GestureLibrary inside Fragment Activity not working

Tags: java, android

how to load Gesturelibrary inside Fragment Activity ...Please help me

```
 @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
       //error is here..."this" is not working 
              mLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);

            gestureOverlayView = (GestureOverlayView)view.findViewById(R.id.gestureOverlayView);



       return  view;

        }
```

Comment: did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be asking for `context` and it's throwing error because `fragment` doesn't have `context`.
Try to use like this:

```
mLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(getActivity(), R.raw.gestures);
```

Comment: finsh() method is also not working inside the Fragment Activity